# TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 wireless adapter not working. Ubuntu is installed in VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

**I bought this device**

TL-WN823N VER 3.0

**I use version of ubunto:**

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Release:    20.04

**And I downloaded a driver from here**

TL-WN823N(EU)_V3_160315_Linux

https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/tl-wn823n/#Driver

Then I did make command
And I get the errors , what i need to do , please help , thx

```
> "******************************************" "NO SKRC,we will use
> default KSRC" "******************************************" make
> ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-38-generic/build
> M=/home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver  modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic'
> "******************************************" "NO SKRC,we will use
> default KSRC" "******************************************"   CC [M] 
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
> In file included from
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:
> In function ‘_init_timer’:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:267:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’  
> 267 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
>       |        ^~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:268:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean
> ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]   268 | 
> init_timer(ptimer);
>       |  ^~~~~~~~~~
>       |  _init_timer In file included from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:35,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/wifi.h:
> At top level:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/wifi.h:994:
> warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined   994 | #define
> IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
>       |  In file included from ./include/net/cfg80211.h:22,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:81,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> ./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the
> previous definition  1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
>       |  In file included from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:95,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/hal_com.h:413:13:
> error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol   413 |
> extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
>       |             ^~~~~~~~~ In file included from ./include/linux/huge_mm.h:8,
>                  from ./include/linux/mm.h:703,
>                  from ./include/linux/bvec.h:14,
>                  from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:17,
>                  from ./include/net/net_namespace.h:39,
>                  from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:37,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> ./include/linux/fs.h:2870:14: note: previous declaration of
> ‘file_path’ was here  2870 | extern char *file_path(struct file *,
> char *, int);
>       |              ^~~~~~~~~ In file included from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:65,
>                  from /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:
> In function ‘btinfo_evt_dump’:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19:
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be   187 |  #define
> _seqdump seq_printf
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’   242 |    if(_seqdump(sel,
> fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
>       |       ^~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3293:2:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’  3293 | 
> DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "cid:0x%02x, len:%u\n", info->cid, info->len);
>       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19:
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be   187 |  #define
> _seqdump seq_printf
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’   242 |    if(_seqdump(sel,
> fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
>       |       ^~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3296:3:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’  3296 |  
> DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte2:%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n"
>       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19:
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be   187 |  #define
> _seqdump seq_printf
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’   242 |    if(_seqdump(sel,
> fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
>       |       ^~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3308:3:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’  3308 |  
> DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "retry_cnt:%u\n", info->retry_cnt);
>       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19:
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be   187 |  #define
> _seqdump seq_printf
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’   242 |    if(_seqdump(sel,
> fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
>       |       ^~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3311:3:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’  3311 |  
> DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "rssi:%u\n", info->rssi);
>       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19:
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be   187 |  #define
> _seqdump seq_printf
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’   242 |    if(_seqdump(sel,
> fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
>       |       ^~~~~~~~ /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3314:3:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’  3314 |  
> DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte5:%s%s\n"
>       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o]
> Error 1 make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849:
> /home/liron/Desktop/yyy/TL-WN823N_EU_V3_160315_Linux/Driver] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic'
> make: *** [Makefile:1696: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: The driver is too old for your kernel. Please add output of `lsusb` to your question. You'll need to find another driver.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Please add information to your question. You can [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Ubuntu in a VirtualBox, you don't need to install any Linux drivers.

Use your host machine to connect to the internet. Install Windows drivers if the host machine is Windows.

The virtual machine will be able to use the connection created on the host machine.

Answer (score -1):

#### kernel enables

make sure that your kernel enables **CONFIG_RTL8XXXU_UNTESTED**, [link here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/Kconfig#L26). This means that kernel has it by **default**(driver), otherwise install the driver from GitHub.

- Steps to install this driver, has to be compiled from GitHub:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms #prerequisites
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git #clone github
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes #setup dkms
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11 #build and install module(driver)
sudo depmod -a #refresh module(driver)
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/ #blacklist failing driver
REBOOT #VERY IMPORANT
```

- `git,linux-headers-generic, build-essential,dkms` are the packages you need to build this driver
- `once you have git` you can download the package from terminal (driver not ready for installing)
- `dkms` is a framework to add modules(drivers) for each kernel, a "manager"
- `dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes` is to tell dkms to add this module and the next command is to build and install that driver with **dkms**. Then you refresh that module, meaning to start the module, and everything in Ubuntu knows how to run it.
- the `blacklist` is optional is and used for telling Ubuntu to not use those drivers, you can check them out in directory (folder) with `ll /etc/modprobe.d/`. Usually file starts with blacklist **word** then the name of hardware and has extension **.conf**,

  - blacklist-native-rtl18192.conf

#### Linux Headers

check if you have installed them

```
apt list linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

it should return something like this:

```
linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic/jammy-security,now 5.15.0-27.28 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

### install Linux headers

```bsh
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

- `uname` is for showing release information of your system, try `uname -a`
- `r` argument is for showing only **kernel-version**
- everything is **wrapped** in `$()` so the command is executed on the same line

- **reboot system**

#### search for other images

```bsh
apt search linux-image
```

Comment: i did that-  sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  and it return me Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Don
linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic is already the newest version (5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.8.0-53-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-53
  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded,0newly installed 0toremoveand432notupgraded.

Comment: @chili555 The build log also shows that the problem is not with headers.

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: @LiroyLevi did you upgrade distro?, because you have 432 packages waiting to be upgraded, so run `sudo apt upgrade -y` restart computer, drivers usually needs to restart

Comment: i did that and its return Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libfwupdplugin1 libllvm10 libllvm11
  linux-headers-5.8.0-53-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-53
  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic

Comment: linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-55-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-55-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: i did again make and  still get me the errors that i wrote up

Comment: @LiroyLevi add your `lsusb` outcome  in your question and `usb-devices`. If i were you, I would uninstall the driver that you install from realtek because it is old(driver) and maybe the "generic" driver that comes with Ubuntu is all that you need, meaning, not need to add a driver just plug and play

Comment: i on virtual machine ubunto. i did that command lsusb and that return :                    
  us 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: help? u know what i can do ?>

Comment: Did you try the **kernel enable** part in my answer?(edited answer). If not, try that. Edit your question to **virtual machine**, because that's another animal. Sometimes you need to configure your virtual machine.

Comment: i will try again and will update